# Is there any harm in including additional linker flags in g++?

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I am writing c++ code in code::blocks and I am setting my build flags, and linker options. I do not want to change the settings frequently, so I have been compiling everything (c++) with `g++ -Wall -o "%e" "%f" -lSDL -lSDL_image`

even things that have zero sdl code in them. I haven’t seen any malfunctions, so i am just wondering, is there any reason I shouldn't compile with these flags always on.

You can exclude cases where I would be compiling for architectures unsupported by SDL, such as 8bit avr etc.. Are there any other risks to doing this besides architecture incompatibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When gcc is performing the linking stage it will search for the missing symbols from the libraries. If no symbols are used in a library, no mention of that library is added to the executable.

You can easily test this for example in Linux. I compiled a simple C++ program adding random libraries to the compilation command and since I'm not actually using them, they are not needed and thus not linked into the binary.

So practically it might only cause a bit of a slowdown in compilation, or maybe accidentally might find some symbol in a library you didn't mean to include, but it will not cause any other issues.